# Configure gsutil to work with LW-SSO cookie

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, rsync, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am currently trying to configure Google gsutil rsync to work with a light weigh single sign on cookie used by HP ALM to synchronize test set and test lab folders. 
I would imagine that there is some way to modify the .boto file to include the necessary information to authenticate with the web server, but I am unsure how to do so.
Any information regarding configuring gsutil to use a LW-SSO cookie would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since gsutil will use OAuth 2.0 or HMAC credentials to authenticate, since those are the authentication options for Google Cloud Storage, could you explain more what server would be involved that would require a LW-SSO cookie?

Comment: From the HP ALM REST API manual: 
first make a request 
GET /qcbin/rest/is-authenticated 
Server refuses request and returns reference to authentication point.

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
WWW-Authenticate: LWSSO realm=http://[server]:[port]/qcbin/authentication-point 

Client sends a valid Basic Authentication header to the authentication point.

GET /qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate 
Authorization: Basic ABCDE123 

Server validates the Basic authentication headers, creates a new LW-SSO token and returns it as LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY={cookie}

Comment: Thanks for the extra info on how to set the cookie. However, my question was more geared towards what service is going to expect that cookie? Are you using a proxy to GCS that would require that cookie? Otherwise, you are presumably either reading local storage, reading from Amazon S3 (which AFAICT doesn't support it), or GCS, which doesn't support it. The OAuth 2.0 token exchange is extremely similar. Are you wanting an LW-SSO analog or to actually use an external authentication mechanism to authenticate as a Google account?

Comment: I think I may be barking up the wrong tree using google gsutil for what I need to do.  I don't actually need to use any google accounts or web services for my project and the authentication is tied to my networks active directory.  In essence I need to be able to download all of the entries in a specific folder on the HP ALM server and update entries in another folder with information stored within the downloaded data.  I hoped to use gsutil to download all of the entries without writing my own method, but without being able to pass the auth cookie from the serve I doubt it will work.